# problem with @material-ui/core/styles: does not contain an export named 'makeStyles'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

First of all I have to say that I have this problem for more than 2 days and I don't really know what to do more, I searched all over stack overflow and there where some questions that where quit exactly to my question, I tried them, and none of them worked, I searched for documentation and I followed, however I don't know if I was doing it right.

I have to say that I just started to learn React.

Okay, so the error occurs when I use `npm start`, in the terminal, I got a `Failed to compile`, and an error is shown up in the browser:

> 4:16-26 '@material-ui/core/styles' does not contain an export named
> 'makeStyles

I have to mention that i named my js file as styles.js, later on i renamed it as Component.styles.js, because like that react would know it's a style file, i don't really know if it works, however i will let the source where i found it, if you want to check it:
https://towardsdev.com/use-your-makestyles-7d347f9a3e96

Then i have a App.js where i import the js style, like this:

```
 import useStyles from './yourComponent.styles.js';
```

This is my:

yourComponent.styles.js:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  BarStylee: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default useStyles;
```

And this is my:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container,AppBar,Typography,Grow,Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import pens from'./images/pencils.jpg';
import Posts from '../src/components/Posts/Posts.js';
import Form from '../src/components/Form/Form.js';
import useStyles from './yourComponent.styles.js';
const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Container maxidth="lg">
            <AppBar className={classes.BarStyle} position="static" color="inherit">
                <Typography variant="h2" align="center">School</Typography>
                <img  src={pens} alt="pencils" height="150"/>
            </AppBar>
            <Grow in>
                <Container>
                    <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                            <Posts />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                            <Form />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Grow>
        </Container>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of `@material-ui/core` do you have?

Comment: @material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.0

Comment: this is the version that  i have in my package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `mui@5.x` `makeStyles` has been moved into `@material-ui/styles` package. You should install `@material-ui/styles@5` and rewrite your code as:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({...})
```

Comment: but in the code I added i used as you showed

Comment: in the yourComponent.styles.js

Comment: Notice that the import here coming from @material-ui/ __styles__ not from @material-ui/ __core/styles__

Comment: ohh okeii, i just had to install it too, and  it's solved

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as follows

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles/makeStyles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({...})
```